# Spark container launch Failed

Tags: windows, docker, apache-spark, containers

I'm a newbie using both spark and containers, actually, I'm trying to run the spark container on docker windows 11 after downloading the Apache/spark image from the docker hub, but I got the error below when trying to run the container and I don't have any idea how and where I can start the troubleshooting if someone can help me on I will be so grateful

here is the log :

```
2023-03-28 11:47:04 ++ id -u
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + myuid=185
2023-03-28 11:47:04 ++ id -g
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + mygid=0
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + set +e
2023-03-28 11:47:04 ++ getent passwd 185
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + uidentry=
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + set -e
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + '[' -z '' ']'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + '[' -w /etc/passwd ']'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + echo '185:x:185:0:anonymous uid:/opt/spark:/bin/false'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + '[' -z /usr/local/openjdk-11 ']'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + SPARK_CLASSPATH=':/opt/spark/jars/*'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + env
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + grep SPARK_JAVA_OPT_
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + sort -t_ -k4 -n
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + sed 's/[^=]*=\(.*\)/\1/g'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + readarray -t SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + '[' -n '' ']'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + '[' -z ']'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + '[' -z ']'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + '[' -n '' ']'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + '[' -z ']'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + '[' -z ']'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + '[' -z x ']'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + SPARK_CLASSPATH='/opt/spark/conf::/opt/spark/jars/*'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + case "$1" in
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + echo 'Non-spark-on-k8s command provided, proceeding in pass-through mode...'
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + CMD=("$@")
2023-03-28 11:47:04 + exec /usr/bin/tini -s --
2023-03-28 11:47:04 tini (tini version 0.19.0)
2023-03-28 11:47:04 Usage: tini [OPTIONS] PROGRAM -- [ARGS] | --version
2023-03-28 11:47:04 
2023-03-28 11:47:04 Execute a program under the supervision of a valid init process (tini)
2023-03-28 11:47:04 
2023-03-28 11:47:04 Command line options:
2023-03-28 11:47:04 
2023-03-28 11:47:04   --version: Show version and exit.
2023-03-28 11:47:04   -h: Show this help message and exit.
2023-03-28 11:47:04   -s: Register as a process subreaper (requires Linux >= 3.4).
2023-03-28 11:47:04   -p SIGNAL: Trigger SIGNAL when parent dies, e.g. "-p SIGKILL".
2023-03-28 11:47:04   -v: Generate more verbose output. Repeat up to 3 times.
2023-03-28 11:47:04   -w: Print a warning when processes are getting reaped.
2023-03-28 11:47:04   -g: Send signals to the child's process group.
2023-03-28 11:47:04   -e EXIT_CODE: Remap EXIT_CODE (from 0 to 255) to 0.
2023-03-28 11:47:04   -l: Show license and exit.
2023-03-28 11:47:04 
2023-03-28 11:47:04 Environment variables:
2023-03-28 11:47:04 
2023-03-28 11:47:04   TINI_SUBREAPER: Register as a process subreaper (requires Linux >= 3.4).
2023-03-28 11:47:04   TINI_VERBOSITY: Set the verbosity level (default: 1).
2023-03-28 11:47:04   TINI_KILL_PROCESS_GROUP: Send signals to the child's process group.
2023-03-28 11:47:04 
2023-03-28 11:47:04 Non-spark-on-k8s command provided, proceeding in pass-through mode...
```

best regards

Answer (score 1):

I ran to the same problem and I found a solution.
You are missing a command when running the docker container i.e. you're probably running a command similar to this: `docker run spark-image-name`.

If you want to run a Spark application, you should pass your application's arguments to the `docker run` command after the image name.

For example, to submit a Spark application named `myApp.py`, you might use a command like:

```
docker run apache/spark:3.4.0 spark-submit myApp.py
```

If you are trying to run a command other than `spark-submit`, you can pass it as an argument to `docker run` as well. For example:

```
docker run apache/spark:3.4.0 ls -al /opt/spark
```

or

```
docker run apache/spark:3.4.0 /bin/bash
```

These will run a command inside the container, rather than starting a Spark application.